# cgroups: blkio.weight doesn't seem to have the expected effect

Tags: ubuntu, cgroups, lxc

I've got 2 LXC containers with these cgroup settings:

```
lxc.cgroup.blkio.weight = 200
lxc.cgroup.cpu.shares = 200

and

lxc.cgroup.blkio.weight = 800
lxc.cgroup.cpu.shares = 800
```

I have verified in `/sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/lxc/test1-lxccontainer/blkio.weight` is indeed set to 200 on the host OS.

I have verified that `cpu.shares` are split up 80% to container 1 and 20% to container 2.

But when I run this command in both containers:

```
# write a 10GB file to disk
dd bs=1M count=10000 if=/dev/zero of=1test conv=fdatasync
```

I ran a similar test on reads:

```
davidparks21@test-cgroups1:/tmp$ time sh -c "dd if=1test of=/dev/null bs=1M"
10000+0 records in
10000+0 records out
10485760000 bytes (10 GB) copied, 37.9176 s, 277 MB/s

real    0m37.939s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m24.306s
```

The IO speeds see in `iotop` on the host OS are virtually the same between the two containers.

I expected to see container 2 command 80% of the IO access in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you need to use the fair scheduler, I was using the wrong scheduler, and had mis-read a setting (thought I was using fair scheduler, but really wasn't). Swapping to the correct IO scheduler fixed the problem.

To change the IO scheduler (taken from [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-change-io-scheduler-for-harddisk/)):

```
echo cfq > /sys/block/{DEVICE-NAME}/queue/scheduler
```

Comment: Notes on how to do that would enhance the answer.

Comment: Added the link on changing the IO scheduler, it's straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a dd command problem with your system cache have you tried to flush your cache first :

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

And launching dd command with "nocache" option ?